# Make this jQuery toggle snippet target each list item individually

Tags: jquery, categories

I'm currently using this little jQuery toggle snippet to show/hide child categories using the wp_list_categories function;

```
$('.sidebar ul.children').hide(); // Start by hiding child categories

$(".sidebar li.parent-item").hover(function () {
$(".sidebar ul.children").slideToggle("slow");
```

But currently hovering over any list item with the class `parent-item` makes every child menu toggle.

Is there a way to make it work only on the list item that is hovered over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$(".sidebar li.parent-item").hover(function () {
   $(this).find("ul.children").slideToggle("slow");
});
```